# Protractor: How to find an element in an ng-repeat by text?

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm looking to get a specific element inside an ng-repeat in protractor by the text of one of its properties (index subject to change).

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <span class="item-name">
    {{item.name}}
  </span>
  <span class="item-other">
     {{item.other}}
  </span>
</div>
```

I understand that if I knew the index I wanted, say 2, I could just do:

```
element.all(by.repeater('item in items')).get(2).element(by.css('.item-name'));
```

But in this specific case I'm looking for the 'item in items' that has the specific text (item.name) of say "apple". As mentioned, the index will be different each time. Any thoughts on how to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by simplifying @bdf7kt's proposed solution:

```
  element.all(by.repeater('item in items')).each(function(elem) {
    elem.getText().then(function(text) {
      if(text.indexOf('apple') != -1) {
        //do something with elem
      }
    });
  });
```

Also, this particular solution doesn't work for my use case, but I'm sure will work for others:

```
var item = element(by.cssContainingText('.item-name', 'apple'));
//do something with item
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function elementThere(specificText, boolShouldBeThere){
  var isThere = '';
  element.all(by.repeater('item in items')).each(function (theElement, index) {
    theElement.getText().then(function (text) {
      // Uncomment the next line to test the function
      //console.log(text + ' ?= ' + specificText);
      if(text.indexOf(specificText) != -1){
        element.all(by.repeater('item in items')).get(index).click();
        isThere = isThere.concat('|');
      }
    });
  });
  browser.driver.sleep(0).then(function () {
    expect(isThere.indexOf('|') != -1).toBe(boolShouldBeThere);
  });
}

it('should contain the desired text', function () {
  elementThere('apple', true);
}
```

Does this fit your needs?

Answer (score 0):

```
public items = element.all(by.binding('item.name'))
getItemByName(expectedName) {
    return this.items.filter((currentItem) => {
         return currentItem.getText().then((currentItemText) => {
             return expectedName === currentItemText;
         });
    }).first();
}
```

And invoke method like that `this.getItemByName('Item 1')`. Replace `Item 1` with expected string.

Comment: Sorry forgot to add... I also need to get the full item as I need to access the other properties too (I will also need to check the `item-other` of the item returned)